# Fastest way to add to a list elements not in second list

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, listboxitems

I have 2 listBoxes with BindingLists as their data sources. The idea is to make a List builder (as [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742407(v=vs.85).aspx) names it), where first listBox shows currently added columns and second listBox shows the rest of available columns. First list contains `ViewColumn` objects, while the other list contains `string`s. 
I load chosen columns into first listBox from database and then I want to load the rest of available columns into the second listBox (the list itself comes from another place in database). Considering there are no limits on the number of columns, I want to do that in the fastest way possible - what would that be?

Here's some code to visualize that:

```
ViewTable _view;
BindingList<ViewColumn> _viewColumns = new BindingList<ViewColumn>();
BindingList<string> _detailsColumns = new BindingList<string>();

void CustomInitialize()
{
    _view = //get view and its columns

    _viewColumns = new BindingList<ViewColumn>(_view.Columns);
    listBox_CurrentColumns.DataSource = _viewColumns;
    listBox_CurrentColumns.DisplayMember = "Name";

    var detailsTable = //get the list of available columns
    foreach (var row in detailsTable)
    {
        //TODO: if _viewColumns does not contain this value, add it to _detailsColumns
            _detailsColumns.Add(row.ColumnName);
    }

    listBox_AvailableColumns.DataSource = _detailsColumns;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do something like:

```
_detailsColumns = _allColumns.Except(_viewColumns.Select(c => c.Name))
```

This should get you all entries in the `_allColumns` collection excluding the entries in the `_viewColumns` collection.
I assume here that `_allColumns` contains the overall collection of possible columns.

Comment: The `_allColumns` you are talking here about is `detailsTable` in my example, however it returns a list of objects where `ColumnName` is just one of many properties, so I also have to do this: `var temp1 = detailsTable.Select(d => d.ColumnName).ToList();`. Nonetheless, that solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: Oh yes. I misunderstood your example a little bit. But I'm glad my answer helped you anyways.